# How can I take values from one table, based off the values in another?

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

Say I have tables

```
    Parts
    PartID (Primary Key)
    Part Name

    Orders
    OrderID (Primary Key)
    CustID (Foreign Key)

    OrderDetails
    OrderDetailsID (Primary Key)
    PartID (Foreign Key)
    Quantity
    OrderID (Foreign Key)
```

If I wanted to get Part Name for multiple PartIDs from OrderDetails, how would I go about doing this? Would I use two DataTables? I'm confused as I cannot see an efficient way to do this. The only thing that I can think of is to create a DataTable with SQL:

```
    SELECT * FROM OrderDetails WHERE OrderID=OrderID;
```

and then maybe use a For loop to take each PartID, create another DataTable to find the PartName for that and then give this to a variable. There could be up to 10 PartIDs to search through and I don't want to have variables such as PartID1 PartID2 etc.

I hope I have been able to convey my problem effectively.

Thanks

EDIT:

```
    SQLCmd = "SELECT tblParts.PartID, tblParts.PartName, tblOrderDetails.Quantity, OrderDetails.OrderID FROM tblOrderDetails, tblParts "
    SQLCmd = SQLCmd & "WHERE tblParts.PartID = OrderDetails.PartID AND OrderID=" & OrderID & ";"
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused, this sounds like a simple query?  Select od.OrderDetailsID, p.Part_Name, od.Quantity, od.OrderID From OrderDetails od, Parts p Where p.partid = od.partid  possibly even just a basic view could handle.

Comment: @mike - Yeah, I'd go for something like that, although I'd prefer specifying the join.  But what's up with `Orders`?  That looks like some nasty de-normalization.

Comment: You would not want to store partid in orders as it is a one to many realtionship.

Comment: I just had a go with the code that I have edited into the original post and it's not retrieving any values - it may be a simple query as I'm fairly new to SQL and probably try to overcomplicate things. I was wondering if you could look over the SQL code? EDIT: And sorry, I meant to put CustID into Orders.

Comment: @X-Zero absolutely agreed.  The orders table does not seem to really serve any purpose given the schema.

Comment: There is really no good reason to name a table "tblParts"  given the way database management tools work and how schemas are organized you should simply name your tables after what they represent. pre-fixing or post-fixing names with an identifier like that is about as big a sin as naming a data variable after its type!

Comment: You have: `OrderDetails.OrderID`... It would make more sense to call the table OrderDetails but from the rest of the code this seems to be missing "tbl" in front of "OrderDetails".

Comment: @Mike McMahon, Orders seems to keep the CustID from being duplicated across many OrderDetails. I think your comment came after the OP corrected that.

Comment: @TimLehner you would be correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `join`. The syntax depends slightly on what kind of SQL you are using, however it will generally look something like this:

```
SELECT `Part Name`
FROM Parts p
INNER JOIN OrderDetails o ON p.PartID = o.PartID
WHERE o.OrderDetailsID = ...;
```

As far as I understand it, this will create a temporary table which consists of the fields of both tables combined. In theory it would create one record in the combined table for each possible combination of records from the two original tables. To cut this down to a reasonable number, you introduce the relation `p.PartID = o.PartID`, which reduces it to only those combinations which are about the same `PartID`.

Inner join means that it will only select from orders which have a part ID associated and only parts which are in an order. `LEFT` and `RIGHT` join are able to do the opposites - select all parts even if they are not in an order (left) or all orders even if they have no parts (right).

W3Schools has some more on joins here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: -1 for using SQl antipattern of implicit joins especially to someone who clearly doesn't understand them.

Comment: I did some revision and edited the post. Please correct me if I'm giving wrong information, I can't say I'm an expert on joins myself.

Comment: INNER JOIN worked like a charm and thank you for providing learning resources!

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
SELECT o.orderID, p.partname, od.quality
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN orderdetails od ON o.orderID = od.orderID
INNER JOIN parts p ON od.partID = p.partID
```

Personally though I would store the partname and price in the order details to have a historical reocrd of what was actually ordered. After all you wouldn't want the historical order to change if the price went up for instance.